# Rails nested variables without more models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested

I'm using Rails 4 and have a `Policy` model. This model has a ton of attributes that I would like to organize in sub-groups of sorts. This is an example:

A policy has base information such as name, address, type. Is there a way to organize the model such that I can do `policy.base_information.name` or `policy.base_information.address` without making another model base_information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`serialize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize) with [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) to accomplish the task.

**Serialize**

> If you have an attribute that needs to be saved to the database as an object, and retrieved as the same object, then specify the name of that attribute using this method and it will be handled automatically.

**OpenStruct**

> An OpenStruct is a data structure, similar to a Hash, that allows the definition of arbitrary attributes with their accompanying values. This is accomplished by using Ruby’s metaprogramming to define methods on the class itself.

---

Call the `serialize` method on `:base_information`, which is an `OpenStruct`:

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :base_information, OpenStruct
end
```

So, now the following would be possible:

```
policy = Policy.create(:base_information => { "name" => "vasseurth" })

Policy.find(policy.id).base_information 
# => { "name" => "vasseurth" }

Policy.find(policy.id).base_information.name
# => "vasseurth"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This looks like it should work, but do you know if it will work with best_in_place (i.e. an in-line editor)?

Comment: I'll test this out and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: I'll accept since it answered my original question, but I couldn't get it to work with best_in_place

Comment: @Vasseurth, it would be great if you update my answer with your work around for best_in_place gem. This will definitely help others in future. :)